# Trouble with adding desired capabilities for Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Trying to add the desired capabilities into start inspector session, added the `platformName`, `platformVersion`, `deviceName`, `automationName`, and `app`.

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "11.4",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 8 Plus",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "app": appName 
}
```

Getting the following error:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

> Original error: Could not find app at '"folder location"'

The folder location is correct.

Comment: Most likely the folder location is not correct. Are you using absolute or relative folder location? If you're using absolute, check for any minor typos. If relative, then it should be relative to where the command to run the program is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "app" capability, please use the absolute path of your app, all the way to the .app file. The path also needs to be enclosed in "". Sometimes, if you're copy-pasting the path over from a text file into Appium Inspector, the " character can get encoded into a different " character, so make sure you're typing the " character in manually in Appium Inspector.